# ld: Framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, tvos

Trying to install Alamofire via Cocoapods. This is a brand new app with zero configuration. I've `pod install` the app and opened the project via it's workspace. Receiving following error using XCode 7.1.

```
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


platform :ios, '9.0'

# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!



target 'Bitcoin Watcher' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1'

end

target 'Bitcoin WatcherTests' do

end

target 'Bitcoin WatcherUITests' do

end
```

`Pods.framework` is found in my `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. This is absolutely frustrating as I've tried numerous solutions but none work. Cocoapods version is `0.39`.

Comment: I faced this error but In my case i build the project once and then it stopped showing error. Just try this.

Comment: I've both cleaned and built the project. The error still appears.

Comment: Can't something be wrong with project name? Try removing you "targets" and just write "pod 'Alamofire'".

Comment: Make sure your `xcodebuild -version` is the version you'd expect. Also make sure your CocoaPods installation is up-to-date at `0.39.0`.

Comment: Same thing here, did u manage to get it working?

Comment: @cnoon, I'm using `0.39.0`. I had posted that in my question. Version is as expected.

Comment: I just tested your "EXACT" setup with a `Bitcoin Watcher` app with unit and ui tests and your exact Podfile. Everything works exactly as expected. I'm using CocoaPods 0.39.0 and Xcode 7.1. I'd say you have something corrupted on your system causing the problem. Typical solutions include wiping derived data and your Xcode cache, rebooting, reinstalling Xcode, reinstalling CocoaPods, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will have to clear derived data and see what happens.

Comment: please accept an answer or explain why the current ones don't satisfy you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cocoapods, check the version and update, clean and run the app

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

pod install
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remember that when you install a new version of Xcode, before pod updating/installing, you should first do `sudo gem install cocoapods`. This will update all the gems which might have beenm deleted due to updating of Xcode.

Then remember next step is there should not be any fiels in target space relating to your dependencies, mentioned in pod. This will confuse your Xcode about the relevant files to use for using dependency.

Hence, ensure that dependencies files are mentioned in the pods folder only.

Next remember that in the linker path settings, you should use first `$inherited`  for specifying the path of libraries.

This step should be done before installing any dependency.

Lastly `cmd+ Shift +k` -> Clean the project should be done before using `pod Install` from terminal.

Jason in your case xcode is unable to link framework, so do mentioned in above steps.

Hope it answer all your questions

Comment: I've already done all of these things and I'm still receiving the error.

Comment: jason I am sorry to hear that. But when I received this error, my problem was solved. Do check Build settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a project for tvOS, you should specify

```
platform :tvOS, '9.0'
```

instead. I don't know if this will solve all of the problems, but it will get you closer for sure.